# Numpy Matrix values to complex values in the form of 0+Value*i

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, complex-numbers

I have a matrix in the form of `a = numpy.matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6', dtype=complex)` of course giving the output:

`a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]`

I'm trying to get this matrix to the form of:

`a = [0+1*i 0+2*i 0+3*i; 0+4*i 0+5*i 0+6*i]`

I can step through this in a loop like:

```
for i in range(2):

    for j in range(1):

         a[i,j] = complex(0, a[i,j])
```

The only problem is my matrix is quite a bit larger than a 2x3. I'd like to use `a.astype(complex)` but this gives me an output of:

`a = [1+0i 2+0i 3+0i; 4+0i 5+0i 6+0i]`

How can I use `astype` to get my matrix to my desired output with the matrix values as the imaginary components?

I am of course, open to other suggestions to speed this up instead of looping through a million values in an array.

Thank you!

~Ave

Comment: `a * np.complex('j')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang works perfectly thanks. I was definitely overthinking things